# How to enable `Go to File Member..` shortcut in Resharper plug in?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am using VS 2013 with Resharper 9.1. Please help in locating the setting to enable `Go to File Member..` shortcut highlighted in below image.

[image]

Comment: It looks like this setting is auto enabled for other projects in same solution so there is some mystery here.

Comment: What language is that file?

Comment: Is that C# file part of the project? Is it being analysed (does it have the ReSharper green tick/yellow triangle/red circle above the scrollbar)? What's the filename (perhaps it's being treated as a generated file)? Does go to file member work for other C# files in that project? And, what happens if you show the File Structure window?

Comment: Yes it is C# file. There is no resharper symbol for any file in this project. One of the file name is UpdateMonitor.cs. Go to member is not working for any c# file for this project. File Structure window does not recognize files from this project at all. This is perfectly working fine on other computer.

Comment: Its funny, After removing and adding this project from solution has fixed the issue. Not sure whats going on here. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing and adding project from solution has fixed the issue.